# Jenkins search in choice parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have plus 1000 items in a list parameter, and I want another field or box next to it, to search and selet one item in that list.

I'm on jenkins 2.32

Is it possible ?

[image: example]

I'm using the Extensible Choice Plugin :
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Active Choices plugin can do it, but it is not safe anymore. is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Have you tried using the browsers search functionality? With Chrome it should work just fine.

Comment: "Have you tried using the browsers search functionality?" - I tried, sadly it's not working in chrome.